# Get columns' names in Excel file using Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

How to get the column names in an Excel file using Apache POI, to make sure that the columns are ordered as expected.

Comment: Do you mean "A", "B", ...?  If not, what do you mean by column names?  Columns are normally "named" by putting names in a top row.

Comment: @Ed Staub is it possible to get "A" and "B", i have a similar requirement

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Or this:

```
cell.getSheet().getRow(0).getCell(currentcellIndex)
    .getRichStringCellValue().toString()
```

Row indexes start from 0.

Comment: If anyone can confirm whether rows start from 0 or not, that would be good. "Not sure if" is not ideal to have in an accepted answer.

Comment: @halfer I think that depends on how excel sheet in created.

Comment: @halfer Yes. Row's index start from 0.

Answer (score 36):

There is a convenience method for this:

```
CellReference.convertNumToColString(cell.getColumnIndex());
```

To get the full name:

```
private static String getCellName(Cell cell)
{
    return CellReference.convertNumToColString(cell.getColumnIndex()) + (cell.getRowIndex() + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Apache POI, translating Excel column number to letter

```
      FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(
      new File("D:\\workspace\\Writesheet.xlsx"));
      @SuppressWarnings("resource")
      XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
      XSSFSheet spreadsheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

      int lastcell=spreadsheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
      //Non empty Last cell Number or index return

      for(int i=0;i<=lastcell;i++)
      {
          try
          {
              System.out.println(CellReference.convertNumToColString(i));
          }catch(Exception e)
          {}
      }
      fis.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

To get cell name:

```
String cellName = new CellAddress(intRow, intCol).toString();
```

Comment: please add more explanation