# get Excel Sheet Column Name of a Chosen Cell using Java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I've a problem with **importing** excel sheet data to work with Java. I've a Table that look likes the following.

---

Image    |     Name         |    Order

---

1011V    |      Holly       |     ON-10121

---

As you can see, I've column Headings ,

- Image
- Name
- Order

I want to get the Column Name like A , B  or C in Excel, given that I've provided the Column Headings ( Cell Values ) Image , Name or Order.

For Example Something like :- getExcelColumnName("Image") , getExcelColumnName()

Comment: Are you exporting to excel, or opening an excel file?  Either way, if you can use .csv files (which excel supports), it will make your life a lot easier.

Comment: @WolfLink Yes , its importing.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to know header no of 5th Column then you have cell no 5. Take cell of row 1 and 5th Column by.

```
 Cell cell = Sheet1.getRow(0).getCell(5);
```

now take a string

```
 String cellNumber = cell.getReference();
```

It will give you `E1`. I have given you an idea of using `cell.getReference();` you can use it by many ways to get the desired result.

Comment: In which api yuo got cell.getreference() method, I am using Apache POI and cell do not have any such method

Answer (score 0):

I found the following API will work:
      CellReference.convertNumToColString(5)
will return "F"

Answer (score 0):

I got this answer usefull..

```
  int lastcell=spreadsheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
  //Non empty Last cell Number or index return

  for(int i=0;i<=lastcell;i++)
  {
      try
      {
          System.out.println(CellReference.convertNumToColString(i));
      }catch(Exception e)
      {}
  }
```

static

```
      Cell cell = spreadsheet.getRow(0).getCell(2);
      tmp=64+cell.getColumnIndex();
      //convert ascii code to character
      System.out.println(Character.toString((char)tmp));
```

Visit Full Describe : [Get columns' names in Excel file using Apache POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8202319/get-columns-names-in-excel-file-using-apache-poi/41821007#41821007)